# How to scrape a hidden element

Tags: python, selenium, web-scraping, beautifulsoup, web-crawler

I am trying to scrape the tbody under the following element of https://steamdb.info/app/730/graphs/. (I gained permission for scraping)

```
<div id="chart-month-breakdown" class="table-responsive">
```

However, when trying to scrape the content or access it through Selenium, I can't because it appears as such:

```
<div id="chart-month-breakdown" class="table-responsive" hidden="">
```

The 'hidden' tag only disappears when I manually browse the page, thus not able to scrape through requests.get.

Is there a way to get the content?

Comment: Please check the answer now. It works fine.

Answer (score 0):

If you are good with stats, here are all the stats that table uses. they fetch table data from api. You can make api calls directly by using this:

```
import requests
headers = {'referer': 'https://steamdb.info/app/730/graphs/','x-requested-with': 'XMLHttpRequest','user-agent': 'Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 10.0; Win64; x64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/86.0.4240.198 Safari/537.36'}
a = requests.get('https://steamdb.info/api/GetGraph/?type=concurrent_week&appid=730',headers = headers).text
print(a)
```

If you are using selenium. I have tried changing hidden to nothing and that got me all the data. You can use selenium javascript to make that div id visible. You can try something like this:

```
javaScript = "document.getElementById('chart-month-breakdown').removeAttribute('hidden');"
driver.execute_script(javaScript)
time.sleep(3) # To let the data poplulate
```

Comment: Tried adding user agents, but did not work; did you try the code?